# Android studio textview goes off screen with constraintlayout on emulator

Tags: android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I am a novice in android app development.
i am trying to do simple title. On design view it looks perfect but at emulator it looks bad and goes off screen.

I used constraintlayout and guidelines to support all screen sizes.

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:fontFamily="@font/antoniofont"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:text="@string/app_header"
android:textSize="60sp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline5"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline6"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline7" />
```

[image: Design view]

[image: Emulator]

Comment: Please include the complete layout file, not just that one element. We need to see the context, including the definitions of the guidelines that it is constrained to.

Comment: It looks like you are constraining the text to a box defined by the four guidelines. I am guessing that that box on the emulator is wide enough to accommodate the text on one line but the box on the emulator is not wide enough. How you would correct this depends on your design and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes and i think it works perfectly.
Added -

```
app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="70sp"
app:autoSizeMinTextSize="30sp"
app:autoSizeStepGranularity="3sp"
app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/antoniofont"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:text="@string/app_header"
    android:textSize="60sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline7" />
```